# Required Fields Based On Multi-Select Picklist Value Formula

Tags: validation-rule, administration

I am creating a validation rule on the Opportunity object.

When a certain service is selected on the **"Services Included"** (services_included__c) multi-select picklist field, I need it to require certain fields on the page if they are blank.

**Example:**

- If Pen Test - External is one of the services selected

[image]

- It should require all the fields in this section of the page

[image]

I tried this formula but its not successful:

```
AND(
    INCLUDES (Services_Included__c, "Pen Test - External") &&
    ISBLANK (Why_Driving_factors_for_Pen_Test_EP__c),
    ISBLANK (Specific_compliance_requirement_EP__c),
    ISBLANK (Desired_time_for_test_to_be_conducted_ET__c),
    ISBLANK (Is_on_site_testing_required_ET__c),
    ISBLANK (Total_number_of_active_IPs_EP__c),
    ISBLANK (How_many_web_applications_are_included_E__c),
    ISBLANK (Any_devices_that_might_impact_the_test_E__c),
    ISBLANK (Any_restrictions_to_be_considered_EP__c),
    ISBLANK (Specific_objectives_to_be_noted_EP__c),
    ISBLANK (Third_Party_hosted_environment_EP__c)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in an answer to one of your previous questions, you shouldn't mix `AND()` and `&&`. Either one is fine, but pick one and stick with it. Mixing and matching like you're doing here can lead to simple bugs that take longer to figure out and fix.

The other main issue is that your concept of when/how validation rules fire appears that it might not be correct. This is a mistake that a lot of people make, so you're in good company. **Validation rules prevent a record from being saved when the result is `TRUE`**.

Right now, your validation rule is saying "If Services_Included__c has our special value, and *all of these other fields* are blank, then complain"<sup>1</sup>. If even one of those fields is populated, the overall result is `FALSE` and your validation rule would let it through.

What you want your validation rule to say is, "If Services_Included__c has our special value, and *any of these other fields* are blank, then complain". Put another way (closer to what your validation rule will look like)...

"If Services_Included__c has our special value, and field1 is blank or field2 is blank or ... fieldN is blank, then complain".

In pseudocode (pseudoformula?)

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Services_Included__c, 'special value'),
    OR(
        field1 is blank,
        field2 is blank,
        ...
        fieldN is blank
    )
)
```

<sup>1: Or rather, that seems to be the *intention* of the rule. Using that `&&` in there makes it so that you're checking if field2 ... fieldN are all blank, and if (picklist check && field1 is blank).

The difference there is that if field1 is not blank, the rest of the validation rule is effectively ignored.

Again, mixing `AND()`; `OR()`; and `NOT()` with `&&`; `||`; and `!` is just setting yourself up for really subtle issues that are hard to identify (but easy to fix once you find them)</sup>